# Postgres keeps rejecting Patroni connection attempts

Tags: postgresql, patroni

I am trying to set up Patroni (2.0.1) for the first time with PG12.

Even though the authentication users specified in the config exist in PG (with correct passwords), PG keeps on rejecting the connection.

This is my config -

```yaml
scope: postgres
name: postgresql0
restapi:
    listen: postgresql0_ip:8008
    connect_address: postgresql0_ip:8008
zookeeper:
    hosts: [...]
bootstrap:
    dcs:
        ttl: 30
        loop_wait: 10
        retry_timeout: 10
        maximum_lag_on_failover: 1048576
        postgresql:
            use_pg_rewind: true
    initdb:
    - encoding: UTF8
    - data-checksums
    pg_hba:
    - host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
    users:
        admin:
            password: admin
            options:
                - createrole
                - createdb
postgresql:
    listen: postgresql0_ip:5432
    connect_address: postgresql0_ip:5432
    data_dir: /data/patroni
    pgpass: /tmp/pgpass
    authentication:
        replication:
            username: replicator
            password: password
        superuser:
            username: supahuser
            password: thesupass
    parameters:
        unix_socket_directories: '.'
        logging_collector: "on"
        log_directory: "/var/log/postgresql"
        log_filename: "postgresql-12-main.log"
    bin_dir: /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin
tags:
    nofailover: false
    noloadbalance: false
    clonefrom: false
    nosync: false
```

These are Patroni's logs -

```
2020-10-07 19:25:16,240 INFO: establishing a new patroni connection to the postgres cluster
2020-10-07 19:25:16,374 INFO: establishing a new patroni connection to the postgres cluster
2020-10-07 19:25:16,378 WARNING: Retry got exception: 'connection problems'
postgresql0_ip:5432 - accepting connections
2020-10-07 19:25:16,399 INFO: establishing a new patroni connection to the postgres cluster
2020-10-07 19:25:16,404 ERROR: Exception when changing replication slots
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/patroni/ha.py", line 1422, in _run_cycle
    return self.process_unhealthy_cluster()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/patroni/ha.py", line 939, in process_unhealthy_cluster
    if self.is_healthiest_node():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/patroni/ha.py", line 770, in is_healthiest_node
    if self.state_handler.is_leader():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/patroni/postgresql/__init__.py", line 338, in is_leader
    return bool(self._cluster_info_state_get('timeline'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/patroni/postgresql/__init__.py", line 318, in _cluster_info_state_get
    raise PostgresConnectionException(self._cluster_info_state['error'])
patroni.exceptions.PostgresConnectionException: "'Too many retry attempts'"
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/patroni/postgresql/__init__.py", line 255, in _query
    cursor = self._connection.cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/patroni/postgresql/connection.py", line 31, in cursor
    self._cursor_holder = self.get().cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/patroni/postgresql/connection.py", line 23, in get
    self._connection = psycopg2.connect(**self._conn_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "supahuser"
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/patroni/postgresql/slots.py", line 45, in sync_replication_slots
    self.load_replication_slots()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/patroni/postgresql/slots.py", line 27, in load_replication_slots
    cursor = self._query('SELECT slot_name, slot_type, plugin, database FROM pg_catalog.pg_replication_slots')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/patroni/postgresql/slots.py", line 22, in _query
    return self._postgresql.query(sql, *params, retry=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/patroni/postgresql/__init__.py", line 274, in query
    return self._query(sql, *args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/patroni/postgresql/__init__.py", line 270, in _query
    raise PostgresConnectionException('connection problems')
patroni.exceptions.PostgresConnectionException: 'connection problems'
2020-10-07 19:25:16,405 INFO: Error communicating with PostgreSQL. Will try again later
```

These are Postgres' logs -

```
2020-10-07 19:25:37.057 UTC [2209766] DETAIL:  Role "supahuser" does not exist.
    Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 98: "host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5"
2020-10-07 19:25:37.061 UTC [2209767] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "supahuser"
2020-10-07 19:25:37.061 UTC [2209767] DETAIL:  Role "supahuser" does not exist.
    Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 98: "host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5"
```

This is proof the users exist with the correct passwords -

```
postgres=# \du
 Role name  |                         Attributes                         | Member of
------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 postgres   | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
 replicator | Replication                                                | {}
 supahuser  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication             | {}

postgres=# alter user supahuser with encrypted password 'thesupass';
ALTER ROLE
postgres=# alter user replicator with encrypted password 'password';
ALTER ROLE
```

Anything you guys think I have done incorrectly or overlooked?

Comment: Does your users have the `LOGIN` flag enabled? You can ensure that by running `ALTER USER supahuser WITH LOGIN;`

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to the same cluster all the time?  How did you connect in order to obtain the "proof the users exist"?

Comment: LOGIN is surplus apparently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that your `pg_hba.conf` is too restrictive. Use something like

```
    pg_hba:
    - local all all peer
    - host all all 127.0.0.1/32 trust
    - host all all ::1/128 trust
    - host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

so that Patroni can connect without password.

Comment: But why would that lead to 'role ... does not exist'?

Comment: @jjanes I saw this error message in the question: `FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "supahuser"`

Comment: Right, but that is the client-side message, which is intentionally vague about password failures.  The server side message spells out that the role doesn't exist, it is just that the client isn't told that part.

Comment: You are right. Something else must have been changed as well.